# JOLT JSON transpose multiple elements

Tags: json, transform, transpose, shift, jolt

I'm trying to do a (simple?) transpose using JOLT:

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "AAA": "10000000000",
    "Value": 12345,
    "BBB": "BBBValue",
    "CCC": "CCCValue",
    "DDD": "DDDValue"
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
{
  "DDDValue" : 12345,
  "CCC" : "CCCValue",
  "BBB" : "BBBValue"
}
```

Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "AAANewName": "AAA",
        "@Value": "@DDD",
        "CCC": "CCC",
        "BBB": "BBB"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now, when I try and do this for 2 items in my input:

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "AAA": "10000000000",
    "Value": 12345,
    "BBB": "BBBValue",
    "CCC": "CCCValue",
    "DDD": "DDDValue"
  },
  {
    "AAA": "10000000000",
    "Value": 123456,
    "BBB": "BBBValue",
    "CCC": "CCCValue",
    "DDD": "DDDValue"
  }
]
```

I get the following output:

```json
{
  "DDDValue" : [ 12345, 123456 ],
  "CCC" : [ "CCCValue", "CCCValue" ],
  "BBB" : [ "BBBValue", "BBBValue" ]
}
```

But I don't want that, I want the items to "stay separate". Do I need another transform? Or can I just change the first one somehow to get the desired output like this:

```json
[
  {
    "DDDValue": 12345,
    "CCC": "CCCValue",
    "BBB": "BBBValue"
  },
  {
    "DDDValue": 123456,
    "CCC": "CCCValue",
    "BBB": "BBBValue"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square bracketed notations containing substitution operator(`&`) for them such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@Value": "[&].@DDD",
        "CCC": "[&1].&",
        "BBB": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]